# Finite convergence radius

Tags: analysis

can somebody explain the fact that an analytic function like arctan(x) ( it can thus be  written as a power series ) on the whole R, has a finite convergence radius ( and not an infinite one as one might expect ). Can somebody demonstrate this ?

I will be very thankfull to any answer.
Ivo

Comment: "Demonnstrate" that the series has a finite radius of convergence? You have a problem with that?

Comment: @ivo You will likely get much better and more useful responses if you explain what you have tried already, so people can see where in particular you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into the complex realm.
$$
(\arctan x)'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.
$$
As a real function, it is$C^\infty$ on its domain. But if you look at it in the complex plane (that is, consider x a complex number), then it has a singularity at $x=\pm i$. This implies centered at $0$ hat the largest circle in which it is analytic has radius one.

Alternatively, you can compute
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}.
$$
The radius of convergence of the series is $1$.

Comment: It's unclear that you take another function (arctanx)' rather then arctanx. Are you thus assuming that the derivative of a fuction conserves the radius of convergence ?

Comment: Yes. $f$ and $f'$ have the same radius of convergence.